# Using cross apply to query nested arrays in json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have what is probably a relatively easy query but I cannot get my head around how to query nested json arrays. I have a SQL 2016 DB with a json field which contains a json string with multiple child arrays.

Attached is an image of the json data:

[image]

I would like to query the "identification" data (99999829250103)

I can query data such as the accountId (LOADACC001) or nickname (LoadTest) using the following query but cannot query from the "account" array:

```
   SELECT top 1
      accountId as NonUserAccountId
   FROM [DBName].DBSchema.transactions t
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t.BankDataText, N'$.data')
   WITH 
   ( 
         accountId VARCHAR(100) 'strict $.account.accountId'
   )
   where t.Id = 675
```

The field 'BankDataText' contains the json string and the table is called 'transactions'. when I add another CROSS APPLY to the query no rows are returned.

Comment: Please post the entire json in a textual (non-image) format

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you just need to extract the nested json section with `as json` and then use another `cross apply` with `open json` to read the inner `account` section:

```
declare @tmp table ([id] int, BankDataText nvarchar(max))
declare @j nvarchar(max)='{
    "data": [{
        "account": {
            "account": [{
                "schemaName": "SortCodeAccountNumber",
                "identification": "99999829250103",
                "name": "Load testing ....",
                "secondaryIdentification": "123456789"
            }],
            "accountType": "null",
            "accountSubType": "null",
            "description": null,
            "accountId": "LOADACC001",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "nickname": "LoadTest",
            "servicer": {
                "schemaName": "BICFI",
                "identification": "PAPAUK00XXX"
            }
        }
    }]
}'
insert into @tmp select 675, @j

select top 1
    A.accountId as NonUserAccountId,        B.identification
from @tmp t
    cross apply openjson (t.BankDataText, N'$.data') with
    ( 
        accountId varchar(100)  'strict $.account.accountId',
        account   nvarchar(max) 'strict $.account.account' as json 
    ) A
    cross apply openjson(A.account) with 
    ( 
        identification varchar(100)
    ) B
```

Result:

[image]